# Can I use the Copy app to sync the home folders of two PCs together?

Tags: sync, cloud

When Ubuntu One died a tragic death, for many users including myself the very awesome [Copy app](https://copy.com?r=lbpFoQ) took its place. While Copy has many advantages, one disadvantage is that anything you want to sync needs to be in one single folder called `Copy` in your Home folder. Ubuntu One was able to sync entire folders within `~`, but Copy can only sync `~/Copy`.

On my computer that is connected to my Copy account, I circumvented this by placing symbolic links inside `~/Copy` that point to the folders in my Home folder that I want backed up.

Is it possible to add another computer to the mix, and have Copy back up and transfer all my files from the same folders in `~` between both computers? That way, I have Computer 1 backed up to the cloud, and Computer 2 backed up to the cloud; and whenever there is a change on Computer 1 or Computer 2, the change is made on the cloud and on the other computer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as that is what I do.

I'll assume that on your first computer, your files are in ~/Documents, ~/Pictures etc and you've created symbolic links to ~/Copy/Documents, ~/Copy/Pictures.

On your second computer, synchronise your Copy folder with the cloud (or copy it across using network/USB etc), and then create the symbolic links from ~/Copy/Documents etc to ~/Documents

Job done :)